# How to link changeset to workitem?

Tags: azure-devops, tfvc

We are using Visual Studio Online and TFVC [not Git] for source control, When we commit our code we always check in the work item id or Bug number as part of checkin comment like following,

```
#1234 Fixed console error.
```

Is there a way we can automatically link these changesets to workitem?

Comment: What do you mean automatically link these changesets to workitem? Do you mean do not specify work item id in comment?

Comment: @starianchen-MSFT I want to specify work item id in comment using #WorkItemId format and want this changeset linked to the work item. All I am trying to do is link all changes made for a given work item. I hope it makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there isn’t such feature in Visual Studio to link changesets to work item automatically, through comment or UI to link work item manually is the simple way.

Update:

Associate work item to changeset through [Work Items REST API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/work-items#add-a-link):

```
PATCH https://{account}.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/workitems/{work item id}?api-version=1.0
```

Content-Type: `application/json-patch+json`

Body:

```
[
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/relations/-",
    "value": {
      "rel": "ArtifactLink",
      "url": "vstfs:///VersionControl/Changeset/{changeset id}",
      "attributes": {
      "name": "Fixed in Changeset"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

On the other hand, this sample may benefit you: [TFS Api to associate work item with check-in using comment tags](http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2013/02/02/tfs-api-to-associate-work-item-with-check-in-using-comment-tags/)

Comment: Thank you, Is there an API example to link changeset to a work item?

Answer (score 4):

When you check-in using TFVC, you can define a check-in policy and specify that people are required to link workitems to their check-ins.

You can do this in Visual Studio Team Explorer -> Settings and under Team project go to Source Control.

[image]

So every time someone tries to check-in code, they have to associate a work item. This can be done directly from within Visual Studio pending changes.

**Updated**

Doing that will associate your changeset with your workitem, as follows:

[image]

You can add workitems by adding then by id or searching on existing queries.
You can add one or more workitems.

[image]

After that, VSTS will automatically link the changeset and workitem.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I want to automate this so that users don't have to link this manually.

Comment: Users have to link the workitem to the check-in manually. This part can't be automated. When you do so, VSTS/TFS automatically links the changeset with the associated workitems. So this part will be done automatically for you. When you are using TFVC and not git, adding the id to the comment it not the way it works. You have to add the workitem using Visual Studio feature for this. Look at the answer, I edited it to help you. If it is good, please upvote it ;)